# Javascript to open URLs at certain time interval

Tags: javascript

How can I open 30 URLs, one after another, each with 30 seconds delay. Each new URL can open in the same or in new window.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the exact answer you linked to with a small adjustment...

```
var targets = [ //Place target URL here
    'http://www.computer.com/',
    'https://www.yahoo.com',
    'http://www.google.com/',
    'http://www.kompyooter.com/'
];

var iTarget;
var iInterval;

function nextTarget(windowsToOpen){
    window.open( targets[iTarget], 'target' );
    windowsToOpen--;
    if( ++iTarget >= targets.length ) {
        clearInterval(iInterval);
        return;
    }
    if (windowsToOpen > 0) {
        return nextTarget(windowsToOpen);
    }
}

function start() {
    iTarget = 0;
    nextTarget(2);
    iInterval = setInterval( function() {nextTarget(2)}, 30000 );   //time interval here 30000 = 30 Sec
}
```

Comment: That works as I wanted, just one question, what if I wanted to open two links at a time and then delay and then next two? I tried with `window.open('http://google.com');` but it didn't work.

Comment: You could duplicate the log in `nextTarget()`. See updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

```js
let delay = 0;
const step = 30 * 1000;
const urls = Array(30).fill('https://google.com')

for (const url of urls) {
  setTimeout(() => window.open(url), delay);
  delay += step;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work:

```
var urlList = [ <your URLS> ];
var count = 0;
var handle = setInterval( function() {
    // open your window here from urlList[count]
    (++count) >= urlList.length && (clearInterval(handle));
}, 500);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var array = [
"https://www.google.com",
"https://www.facebook.com"
"https://jquery.com",
"https://twitter.com"
]

let x = 0;
setInterval(function(){
  if(x < array.length){
    window.open(array[x++]);
  }
}, 30000);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this.

```js
setInterval(openUrl, 30000); 

 var url = ['https://google.com', 'https://yahoo.com']; // add your 30 URls here
function openUrl(){
for(var i = 0; i < url.length; i++) {
  window.open(url[i]);
  }
}
```